# Cryptographic Key Storage

Tags: c#, encryption

I'm trying to implement file encryption within my project, but I'm wondering as to best practices for key storage.

Our application is deployed to various client groups. Each group consists of multiple geographical sites, each in turn consisting of multiple users. Users create files which are then synchronised with other sites via a central synchronisation server. These files must be encrypted at point-of-save, and only be decrypted when loaded at a client site.

As such, any symmetric key needs to be unique at group-level, and be stored securely at each site.

We're using AES but the key is currently hard-coded and stored within the application, so is both easily accessible via decompilation and the same for all clients, which is worrying me considerably. It seems pretty trivial to hack this kind of setup once you have access to our application.

So, how would one go about ensuring generation of a unique key for each group, and then securely storing that key at each site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only really *secure* way of keeping a single symmetric key is making them enter a passphrase/password and generating a key from that. That way your application doesn't know the key without user input.

Either that or supplying the key in some individual file that they would need to give to the application (via interface, registry or simply placing it at appropriate path) in order for encryption to work.

In the end, security always comes down to the users.

Comment: +1 I agree, I would go a step further and say key should be random, and the key should be encrypted with PBE. That way you can change the password if needed without re-encrypting your files. I've been working on a c# [native port](https://github.com/jbtule/keyczar-dotnet/tree/master/dotnet) of the google [keyczar](http://www.keyczar.org/) project that will be released officially in the near future which in addition to PBE keys it has key rotation and versioning built in.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is a great solution but not one I think I can use. The file encryption key needs to be available to all sites within a group, and the key (or related secret) must only be available to a very small number of superusers. As such, I'd need to store the secret somewhere to allow regular uses to utilise that key.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit out of my league so I'm just telling what I know.

Have you looked at  using certificates and using them in the Windows Certificate Store?

I mean, that's basically the only place to safely store it, I think...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good use case for symmetric cryptography. This is where asymmetric security is actually a requirement. You can distribute public keys (using a PKI, or by distributing it in a trust store within the application). Then you encrypt a symmetric key with the public key of the receiving party (e.g. one of a key pair belonging to the central server or one of a group) and encrypt the actual data with the symmetric key.

Sometimes symmetric cryptography is used this way, e.g. with storage of keys within smart cards, but the key management is always horrific compared to asymmetric cryptography.